# How to use the Atmosphere framework with GlassFish 3.1.2?

Tags: maven-2, glassfish-3, tomcat7, netbeans-7, atmosphere

I just try the [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). I made the [chat sample](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/chat) running in Tomcat 7.0.27 but when I want to run it with GlassFish 3.1.2 then I only get the message:

> "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/catalina/comet/CometProcessor".

What am I doing wrong? I use the built-in GlassFish from NetBeans IDE 7.1.2.

Kindly regards,

Benny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok. I found the solution!** In NetBeans you have to click on "Enable Comet Support" in "Tools" - "Servers" - "GlassFish":

[image: Enable Comet Support in GlassFish]

Comment: Humn... It still shows: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.comet.CometProcessor :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you having similar exception stack trace as in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667058/atmosphere-cant-get-session-on-glassfish-3-1-2)? If your answer is comfirmative then you're facing a bug in glassfish's grizzly-websockets.jar module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its way too late for this answer, but for anyone else, the problem is that the atmosphere catalina jars are missing. These can be gotten from either the atmosphere project or Tomcat. Just be sure to get the correct versions. At the time of this writing, the jars were atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.2.jar and atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.2.jar.