# Atmosphere can't get session on Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, glassfish, websocket, glassfish-3, atmosphere

I got the [chat](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/chat) example working from Atmosphere, and now I want to get the session, but I get a null pointer exception. My configuration:

- GlassFish 3.1.2
- Atmosphere 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

My ChatAtmosphereHandler.java file:

```
@Override
public void onRequest(AtmosphereResource r) throws IOException {

    AtmosphereRequest req = r.getRequest();

    // First, tell Atmosphere to allow bi-directional communication by suspending.
    if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {

    /* ------- ADDED LINES BY ME ------- */
        double i = Math.random();
        System.out.println(i);
        req.getSession(true).setAttribute("user", i); //Null pointer exception
    /* --------------------------------- */
        // The negotiation header is just needed by the sample to list all the supported transport.
        if (req.getHeader("negotiating") == null) {
            r.suspend();
        } else {
            r.getResponse().getWriter().write("OK");
        }
    // Second, broadcast message to all connected users.
    } else if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        r.getBroadcaster().broadcast(req.getReader().readLine().trim());
    }
}
```

And the exception stack trace:

```
INFO: 18:07:19.816 [http-thread-pool-8080(4)] WARN  o.a.websocket.WebSocketProcessor - Failed invoking AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport()
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyRequest.doGetSession(GrizzlyRequest.java:2271) ~[grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyRequest.getSession(GrizzlyRequest.java:2226) ~[grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:986) ~[grizzly-http-servlet.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:1009) ~[grizzly-http-servlet.jar:1.9.46]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.createSession(AtmosphereRequest.java:606) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.getSession(AtmosphereRequest.java:580) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.getSession(AtmosphereRequest.java:600) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.samples.chat.ChatAtmosphereHandler.onRequest(ChatAtmosphereHandler.java:43) ~[ChatAtmosphereHandler.class:na]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:232) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:165) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishWebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishWebSocketSupport.java:111) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1125) ~[atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocketProcessor.dispatch(WebSocketProcessor.java:183) [atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocketProcessor.dispatch(WebSocketProcessor.java:112) [atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishWebSocketSupport$GrizzlyApplication.onConnect(GlassFishWebSocketSupport.java:163) [atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.grizzly.websockets.DefaultWebSocket.onConnect(DefaultWebSocket.java:128) [grizzly-websockets.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(WebSocketEngine.java:188) [grizzly-websockets.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketAsyncFilter.doFilter(WebSocketAsyncFilter.java:54) [grizzly-websockets.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.46]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_03]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session handling code has been modified since then. Please try again with the latest master code.

Comment: Yes it is working now, there have been bugs in both - the grizzly and atmosphere code.